# CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing

I am new to cypress and I am checking my page, and wanted to request method Get, for clicking button after that.

here's my code :

```
 cy.server()
        cy.route('GET', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/').as('getPeople')        
        cy.get('.row').eq(1).click().then(() => {
            cy.wait('@getPeople')
            cy.get('[data-cy=submit]').click({ force: true }).then(() => {
                cy.wait(8000)
                cy.get('p').contains('Films').next().click().then(() => clickHeader())
            })
        })
```

Can anybody help me for that. thankyou!!